# Angular.js how to retry image until available

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use an `imageloaded` directive to fade-in images as they load.

```
 app.directive('imageloaded', [

    function () {

        'use strict';

        return {
            restrict: 'A',

            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                var cssClass = attrs.loadedclass;

                element.bind('load', function (e) {
                    angular.element(element).addClass(cssClass);
                });
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

used thusly

```
 <img ng-src="{{preview.display_url}}" class="animation-fade" imageloaded
                             loadedclass="animation-faded"/>
```

but sometimes the image is not yet available (e.g., queued for resizing), and it takes a few seconds for the url to become available.

If the image has not loaded, I want to try to reload it every 5 seconds. I am stumped on how to do that while encapsulating it in this directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to set up a timeout timer to be checked every 5 seconds. If onload event occurs it will clear current timeout and add class.

Try something like this:

```
app.directive('imageloaded', [

    function () {

        'use strict';

        return {
            restrict: 'A',

            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

                var cssClass = attrs.loadedclass,
                    origSrc,
                    timeout;

                function reload() {
                    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                        if (!origSrc) {
                            origSrc = element[0].src;
                        }
                        element[0].src = origSrc + '?' + Date.now();
                        reload();
                    }, 5000);    
                }

                reload();

                element.bind('load', function (e) {
                    clearTimeout(timeout);
                    element.addClass(cssClass);
                });
            }
        }
    }
]);
```